# Redirecting C# console app's stdout also redirects stdin

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, cat

I'm trying to create a simple C# console app that mimics Linux' cat:

```cs
string? inp;
while ((inp = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inp);
}
```

I'm running this application in Linux (tested with Alpine and Ubuntu), and it seems to work correctly. Everything I type, gets echoed by the app, similar to cat:

```
/app # ./ConsoleTest
abc
abc
def
def
123
123
```

However, when I try to redirect the output to a file, the input doesn't show anymore when I type, but instead gets redirected to the file too:

```
/app # ./ConsoleTest >test.txt
/app # cat test.txt
abc
abc
def
def
123
123
```

This behavior is not equal to cat:

```
/app # cat >test.txt
abc
def
123
/app # cat test.txt
abc
def
123
```

So the question is: why does this not work and how do I get my application to mimic cat when the output is redirected?

Comment: This feels like a bug in .NET. Have you tried reporting it on github?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll try that. I agree that it feels like a bug, I certainly don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @omajid Well, guess what, this was reported years back: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22314